# Linked in integration authentication error

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I have performed the steps described above on LinkedIn Web site is authenticated and try the sample application Any help would be appreciated. The purpose is to verify the application I use LinkedIn to build credentials

I have executed the steps as mentioned on the LinkedIn website for authentication and trying out the sample app getting error...

failed for URL: "linkedin: // authorize" - error : 
 "This app is not allowed to Query for scheme linked"

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please show some code related to your question ...

Have you added your bundle identifier in **LinkedIn** developer account ?
Have you set application transport security related things in **.plist**     **URL scheme** ?